# How to export session variables between files in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, neo4j, graphenedb

I currently have in my server.js file:

```
const neo4j_conn = 'bolt://' + config.neo4j.host;
const driver = neo4j.driver(neo4j_conn, neo4j.auth.basic(config.neo4j.username, config.neo4j.passphrase));
const session = driver.session();
app.set('neo4jsession', session);

require('./app/routes')(app);
```

and in my routes file I have :

```
const session = app.get('neo4jsession');
```

considering that I need only one session per request, is this the right approach for me to connect to the database and get a session back? Can you suggest a better design pattern/ coding method/  for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you open the session, and it is one for the entire server.

You need pass `function` instead result of `function`:

```
app.set('neo4jsession', driver.session);
```

And if we take the example of the router out of the box:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  const session = req.app.get('session')();      
  session
    .run( query )
    .then( function(result)
    {
      res.json( result );
      session.close();
    })
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: In your case, how would you close the session in the / method?